# Linux: Performance issues on LUNs and multipath connections

Tags: rhel, partition

Is there a disadvantage if an operational system has to handle many LUNs rather than just one LUN with many partitions ?
Would an OS performance suffer from handling many multipath connections ?
Would an OS performance suffer if it had only a few multipath conections but many partitions to handle ?